# How to handle non-const lvalue reference to type 'A' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'B' for this pointer?

Tags: c++

Currently I am running into catch 22 situation. I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
class B;

class A{
public:
    A(B& _b):b(_b){}

private:
    B& b;
};


class B{

public:
    B(int _x):x(_x),a(*this){}

private:
    A& a;
    int x;

};

int main(){

  B b(1);

}
```

I use forward declaration here to pass object of class B as parameter in class A. Then I use `rvalue reference` of class B's `this pointer` to pass it to A's constructor. So I know why the compiler is complaining (because of trying to bind rvalue to lvalue reference -- at least this is what I think is happening -- please correct me if I am wrong).

To solve this I try to do

```
#include <iostream>
class B;

class A{
public:
    A(B _b):b(_b){}

private:
    B b;
};
```

...

This again gives error saying `field has incomplete type 'B'` (I used to see this error only when "xxx.h" was not included since compiler did not know the class size) but they are in same Translation unit. Why still is the compiler complaining? Is there any solution to this problem of passing `rvalue this object` or am I falling into bad design?

**For future read** : In addition to peppe's answer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565167/non-const-lvalue-references) also has good description

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any rvalue references.

Comment: @KerrekSB isn't `*this r-value reference`?

Comment: What do you want this code (`a(*this)`) to do?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I wanted A class to have instance to B so that I could call B's method from A.

Comment: @vantamula - But there is no instance of `A` - `a` is a reference.

Comment: @vantamula: Why and how? The result of the `*`-operator is and has always been an lvalue.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth you are right, removing A's reference from class B fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not building any A object. You're trying to set `a` (a lvalue reference) to the temporary A object built using the `A(B &b)` constructor.

In the `a(*this)` expression in the `B(int)` constructor's initialization list, `*this` yields a `B&`, which as-is cannot bind to a `A&` as the two classes are not related.

So, implicit conversions are tried. There's a way to get an `A` out of a `B&`: apply the `A(B &)` constructor to get a temporary `A` object. However, now you've got a *temporary* `A`, and that cannot bind to `a`, which is a non-const lvalue reference. A temporary can only bind to const lvalue references, or rvalue references.

And this is precisely what the compiler is telling you:

```
<source>: In constructor 'B::B(int)':
<source>:16:23: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'
     B(int _x):x(_x),a(*this){}
                       ^~~~~
<source>:6:5: note:   after user-defined conversion: A::A(B&)
     A(B& _b):b(_b){}
```

Comment: ok so u mean `a(*this) ` is rvalue and I am assigning it to lvalue?

Comment: I hope I've explained.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and yes now it makes more sense