# How to put the iterator to nth element of a std::list<class>?

Tags: c++, class, iterator, std, stdlist

I have a custom class `MyData`.

```
class MyData
{
private:
    int data;

public:
    int getData() const
    {
        return data;
    }

    MyData(int val)
        : data(val)
    {
        cout << "Constructor invoked" << endl;
    }

    MyData(const MyData& other)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor invoked" << endl;
        data = other.data;
    }

    MyData& operator =(const MyData& other)
    {
        cout << "Assignment operator invoked" << endl;
        data = other.data;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyData& d)
    {
        cout << "<< operator overloaded" << endl;
        os << d.data;
        return os;
    }
};
```

in my `main` function, I have

```
list<MyData> data2{ 12,21,32,113,13,131,31 };
```

I want my iterator to 4th element,  let's say directly rather than doing an increment `++` operation each time.

How can I do so?

```
list<MyData>::iterator it = data2.begin();
it += 4; // error since I cannot increment this???-compile time error.
```

I am doing like this -

```
it++; it++; it++; it++;
```

What is the correct way so that the iterator directly points to the 4th element?

I tried using advance like `std::advance(data2.begin(),3);`. However, this throws an error saying

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::_List_iterator<MyData>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::list<MyData>::iterator’ {aka ‘std::_List_iterator<MyData>’}
   data1.splice(it, data2,advance(data2.begin(),3),data2.end()); //splice transfer range.
```

Basically, I am doing this for splicing the list from another list with one element or some time range.

Comment: [read doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) (note `&`) and see [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

Comment: Unfortunately [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) iterators are [*bidirectional* iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) which doesn't support arbitrary adding or subtracting values from them. For that you need a [random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), (like what you can get from `std::vector`).

Answer (score 2):

See the reduced version of error message

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type [...]
      to an rvalue of type [...]
```

Meaning, you are trying to bind a *temporary r-value* (i.e. `data2.begin()`) to *non-const iterator reference*. This is [not possible as per the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565167/non-const-lvalue-references). Hence, the compiler error.

When you look at to the [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) signature

```
template< class InputIt, class Distance >
constexpr void advance(InputIt& it, Distance n); (since C++17)
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It expects to the l-value input iterator type.

Therefore, you need

```
auto iter = data2.begin(); // l-value input iterator
std::advance(iter, 3);
```

---

Side notes:

- Need to know more about the c++ value category; See here [Value
  categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).
- Operations such as `it+=4;`, `it++;` are only possible for *[random
  access
  iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)*
  (see the **Expression** s in the link).  But,
  [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has
  only *[bidirectional
  iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)*,
  which does not support the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
auto it = data2.begin();
std::advance(it, 3);
```

You're trying to modify `begin()` itself, that's why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You want `std::next` instead of `std::advance`. The latter will modify the passed in iterator. The former will return a new one.

```
auto it = std::next(data2.begin(), 3);
```