# Why doesn't std::tie work with const class methods?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, tuples, member-functions

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
    public:
        Date() {};
    Date(int new_year, int new_month, int new_day)
    {
        year = new_year;

        if ((new_month < 1) || (new_month > 12))
        {
            throw runtime_error("Month value is invalid: " + to_string(new_month));
        }
        month = new_month;

        if ((new_day < 1) || (new_day > 31))
        {
            throw runtime_error("Day value is invalid: " + to_string(new_day));
        }
        day = new_day;
    }

    int GetYear() const
    {
        return year;
    }

    int GetMonth() const
    {
        return month;
    }

    int GetDay() const
    {
        return day;
    }

    private:
        int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

bool operator < (const Date &lhs, const Date &rhs)
{
    auto lhs = tie(lhs.GetYear(), lhs.GetMonth(), lhs.GetDay());
    auto rhs = tie(rhs.GetYear(), rhs.GetMonth(), rhs.GetDay());

    return lhs < rhs;
}
```

I'm trying to create a class for storing the date (year, month, day). In order to use this class in a map, I want to overload the comparison operator. Unfortunately, the code above does not work. The compiler gives me an error

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'|
```

The error apparently occurs in `tie` function. Once I change it to `make_tuple` everything compiles and works. I also checked that if I declared variables `year`, `month` and `day` as public I could write something like

```
auto lhs = tie(lhs.year, lhs.month, lhs.day);
```

and this would also work.

I don't understand why. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: I can't read the code right now but from the error you mention - binding a reference to a non-`const` temporary is a no-no.

Comment: [This explains it.](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2020/10/16/tie-make_tuple-forward_as_tuple-how-to-build-a-tuple-in-cpp/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your member functions return copy of the members(aka temprory **rvalue**), and [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) has argument list, which try to bind by **non-cost lvalue ref**.

```
template< class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple<Types&...> tie( Types&... args ) noexcept;
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This [is simply not possible as per standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565167/non-const-lvalue-references), hence the error!

---

The [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) on the other hand has **forwarding reference**. Therefore, no issues.

```
template< class... Types >
std::tuple<VTypes...> make_tuple( Types&&... args );
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When the members are public, they became lvalues.

---

I would suggest, make the `operator<` friend of the class instead.

```
class Date 
{
public:
  // .... other code
  friend bool operator<(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) noexcept
  {
    return std::tie(lhs.year, lhs.month, lhs.day) < std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month, rhs.day);
  }

private:
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire purpose of [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is to create a tuple of lvalue references. Your member functions return `int` which aren't lvalues, and so you get an error.

Making the member variables public and using them directly as arguments to `tie` works because variables are lvalues.