# C++ Default Argument using Default Constructor to instantiate

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to have a function that takes a reference to an argument that has a default, where the default is instantiated using its default constructor?

For example:

```
void g(Foo &f = Foo()) {}
```

This does not work, but I feel that it conveys my intention quite clearly.

Comment: That just-amended little non-const lvalue reference makes a world of difference. The answer is no, it isn't possible. And it may convey your intention well to you, but the rest of us... not so much. My crystal ball tells me you're using this recursively?

Comment: @WhozCraig do you know why it isn't possible?

Comment: You're trying to assign a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary value `Foo()`. These references essentially bind to *named variables*. There is no named variable here and thus it will not compile.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565167/non-const-lvalue-references

Comment: A non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary. Basically that's the principle reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References to non-`const` cannot bind to temporary values, and `Foo()` is a temporary `Foo` object.

If you don't need to modify the passed object, then you can make `f` a reference to `const`:

```
void g(const Foo& f = Foo()) {}
```

If you do modify the passed reference, then using a temporary doesn't make much sense, since you'll would be modifying an object that would go out of scope as soon as the function returns.