# Similar types (`int16_t` and `short`) produce different behaviors during reference instantiation

Tags: c++, types, casting, reference, embedded

I'm running into the following error depending on which type I choose for a variable.

```
/home/zak/Development/Arduino/generated_examples/ArduinoIoTCloud_Basic/thingProperties.h: In function 'void initProperties()':
/home/zak/Development/Arduino/libraries/ArduinoIoTCloud/src/ArduinoIoTCloud.h:116:64: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int16_t& {aka int&}' to an rvalue of type 'int16_t {aka int}'
 #define addProperty( v, ...) addPropertyReal(v, #v, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                ^
/home/zak/Development/Arduino/generated_examples/ArduinoIoTCloud_Basic/thingProperties.h:32:16: note: in expansion of macro 'addProperty'
   ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, 2, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
                ^
In file included from /home/zak/Development/Arduino/generated_examples/ArduinoIoTCloud_Basic/ArduinoIoTCloud_Basic.ino:17:0:
/home/zak/Development/Arduino/libraries/ArduinoIoTCloud/src/ArduinoIoTCloud.h:158:15: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Property& ArduinoIoTCloudClass::addPropertyReal(int16_t&, String, int, Permission)'
     Property& addPropertyReal(int16_t& property, String name, int tag, Permission const permission);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is the body of `addPropertyReal()`:

```cpp
Property& ArduinoIoTCloudClass::addPropertyReal(int16_t& property, String name, int tag, Permission const permission)
{
  Property* p = new CloudWrapperInt16(property);
  return addPropertyReal(*p, name, tag, permission);
}
```

The problem happens when `new`ing `CloudWrapperInt16`:

```cpp
class CloudWrapperInt16 : public CloudWrapperBase {
  private:
    int16_t  &_primitive_value,
             _cloud_value,
             _local_value;
  public:
    CloudWrapperInt16(int16_t& v) : _primitive_value(v), _cloud_value(v), _local_value(v) {}
...
```

^^ As you can see, `_primitive_value` is a reference.

### 16-bit architecture, avr-gcc compiler

Oddly, this works when I pass an actual `int` or `int16_t`. However, I run into this error whenever I pass in a value that is equivalent but must be cast into a `int16_t`, like `short`.

**SUCCESS (`int16_t`):** *(compiles without warnings)*

```cpp
int16_t potentiometer;
...
void initProperties() {
...
  ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
```

**SUCCESS (`int`):** *(compiles without warnings)*

```cpp
int potentiometer;
...
void initProperties() {
...
  ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
```

**FAIL (`short`):** *(error shown above)*

```cpp
short potentiometer;
...
void initProperties() {
...
  ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
```

> ***EDIT:** Originally, I forgot to mention that this particular example is compiling for a 16-bit platform. So `int`, `short` and `int16_t` should all be the same size.*

### 32-bit architecture, arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler

In a really bizarre twist, this works when I pass a `short` or `int16_t`. However, I run into a similar error whenever I pass in an `int` value.

**SUCCESS (`int16_t`):** *(compiles without warnings)*

```cpp
int16_t potentiometer;
...
void initProperties() {
...
  ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
```

**SUCCESS (`short`):** *(compiles without warnings)*

```cpp
short potentiometer;
...
void initProperties() {
...
  ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
```

**FAIL (`int`):** *(similar error as shown above)*

```cpp
int potentiometer;
...
void initProperties() {
...
  ArduinoCloud.addProperty(potentiometer, Permission::Read).publishOnChange(10);
```

Can someone explain what exactly is happening here with the type conversion?

I'm looking for a POSIX compliant way for to the compiler to treat them equivalently, or a way to enhance the code to allow this to work. Any solution will need to compile for multiple architectures (16-bit, 32-bit, etc.), as well as work on multiple toolchains (`avr-gcc`, `arm-none-eabi-g++`, etc.).

> ***NOTE:** I don't have control over the code base; it is a large open-source project. I really need a surgical solution, because the more broad the refactor work, the harder it will be to get the PR accepted.*

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Asking about binding a reference doesn't need 20 extra lines of uncompilable code.

Comment: This is a giant open-source library. I don't believe that is possible. Alternatively, I provided the code from the error message to it's source. Instantly down voting without attempting to understand is not appreciated. I don't believe this problem can be solved with Godbolt, or I would have done it myself. It should be somewhat obvious that this is a "type conversion" problem, and I have provided all code related to the origin of the type and its conversion.

Comment: @Zak What is unclear with this error message "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int16_t& {aka int&}' to an rvalue of type 'int16_t {aka int}'??

Comment: The confusion arising from the fact that it can actually bind an `int` (or `int16_t`) without warning, but not a `short`. There is some nuance in the types I do not understand. In this example it is a compiling for a 16-bit platform.

Comment: *"In a really bizarre twist, this works when I pass a `short` or `int16_t`. However, I run into a similar error whenever I pass in an `int` value."* -- There's nothing bizarre about this twist. You still get the error when the type must be cast to `int16_t` (as you noted for the first case: *"whenever I pass in a value that [...] must be cast into a `int16_t`"*). The difference is that in this scenario, `int16_t` is an alias for `short`, whereas in the first example, it was an alias for `int`.

Comment: *"This is a giant open-source library. I don't believe that is possible."* -- As Yoda said, "Size matters not." It's totally possible. Drop things that don't matter. The error message identifies the problem as "argument 1", so drop the other parameters. The problem is calling the function, so the body doesn't matter; drop that and make the return type `void`. `void addProperty(int16_t&)
{}`. Then you just need call sites to demonstrate the three ways to call the function. This is quick and easy: `int main() {
int16_t int16_works = 1;
addProperty(int16_works);
}`. Can you not use this?

Comment: _"I don't believe that is possible"_ your question title is asking why this doesn't compile `short s; int16_t& r = s;`. But that's not even correct, your error message says you're binding a non-const lvalue reference to a rvalue. And if you truly cannot manage to give us a [mre], exactly what kind of magic clairvoyants do you think we are that we can telepathically read into your code base?

Comment: Realistically, [Non const lvalue references cannot be bound to an lvalue of different type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18565167) should be a duplicate, but I guess it does lack the detail that `short` and `int` are distinct types even when they are equivalent (meaning the same number of bits).

Comment: @JaMiT You got tricked, the error says "'int16_t& {aka int&}' to an rvalue of type 'int16_t {aka int}'", that's not binding to a different type.

Comment: @PasserBy If you are referring to my example [mre], my apologies but comments are not long enough. So I trimmed down from `int main() {
int16_t int16_works = 1;
int int_fails = 2;
short short_works = -3;

addProperty(int16_works);
addProperty(int_fails);
addProperty(short_works);
}` (with the second function call failing on a 32 bit system) to something from which I thought an example could be built.

Comment: @JaMiT I was referring to the error message seemingly saying the type is fine but the value category is wrong, which is my mistake. Older gcc apparently [produces bad error messages](https://godbolt.org/z/cs4jGs914).

Comment: Apart from AVR being an extremely resource-tight MCU unsuitable for dynamic allocation (and C++...), there are many technical reasons not to use dynamic allocation at all: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: I totally agree, but unfortunately I do not control this OSS project. I'm just trying to untangle a mess I've discovered.

Comment: I read through the suggested duplicate, and it did make me wonder if there is a temporary variable created during a cast (like from `short` to `int16_t`) that would ultimately defeat the reference mechanism and create an issue like what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***NOTE:** This answer welcomes improvement, and is left solely as a breadcrumb to others. It is based-on empirical observation, and not digging into the source code of the compilers in question or researching the ISO.*

It appears that the `avr-gcc` compiler aliases `int16_t` as `int` (or vice-versa), and `short` is defined separately. While the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler aliases `int16_t` as `short` (or vice-versa).

The successes can be attributed to the fact that they are, in fact, the same data type so **no casting or conversion is required**. As such, the failures are stemming from the fact a conversion or cast is deemed necessary by the compiler.

Once a cast has occurred, a temporary is created. Obviously, a temporary can not be bound to a non-const reference (which makes sense of the error message), because the reference would not have storage associated with it and therefore could not be modified during runtime.

*If you are struggling to conceptualize this, then think of a cast from an integer to a float. It would be impossible to update an underlying integer by modifying a float value.*

In my case, the solution I needed was to further template my integer-based classes and functions. This ultimately abstracted all the integer operations behind a single generic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`short` and `int` are mangled as two different types, namely `short` is mangled as `s` and `int` is mangled as `i`.

Take the following sample code:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

int fun_int (int i) { return 0; }
int fun_int16_t (int16_t i) { return 0; }
int fun_short (short i) { return 0; }
int fun_INT16_TYPE (__INT16_TYPE__ i) { return 0; }
```

And compile with `-Os -S` or `-Os -save-temps=obj`.  The generated assembly then shows the following mangled names:

```
> grep ^_Z foo.s
_Z7fun_inti:
_Z11fun_int16_ti:
_Z9fun_shorts:
_Z14fun_INT16_TYPEi:
```

Notice the last letter, which is `i` for `int` except for the `short` version where it is `s`.

This means you can have polymorphism with `int` vs. `short`, but not amongst any of the `i` types:

```cpp
int ffun (int i) { return i; }
short ffun (short i) { return i; } // OK
int ffun (int16_t i) { return i; } // error: 'int ff(int)' previously defined
```